# mysql fulltext search problem

Tags: php, mysql

Hey, Having a small issue that I don't quite understand with MYSQL fulltext search.
I have this:

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE MATCH (article) AGAINST ('news')"); 

 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo $result['title']; 
 echo "<br><br> "; 
 echo $result['article']; 
 echo "<br><br>"; 
 } 

 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 

 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$search_term;
```

This works fine. It pulls the title, and the article from the database, and echo's out all the information for each item in the database. Only pulls the information from 'article' columnthough..... (If "news" is in the title only, it won't show in the results.)
And this happens vise versa. If I query MATCH (title), it'll only find posts with the given search term in the title, not the article

However, when I change the MATCH clause too: MATCH (title,article), I get zero results. Basically, I'm stuck MATCHing to only one column.

Here is my table schema for the posts table:
(this is from an export)

CREATE TA`BLE`posts (
  `id` int(55) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) collate latin1_german2_ci default NULL,
  `article` text collate latin1_german2_ci,
  `post_type` varchar(255) collate latin1_german2_ci default NULL,
  `day` text collate latin1_german2_ci,
  `user` varchar(55) collate latin1_german2_ci default NULL,
  `month` text collate latin1_german2_ci,
  `year` int(4) default NULL,
  `member_id` int(55) default NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `draft` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `slug` varchar(255) collate latin1_german2_ci default NULL,
  `event_month` varchar(255) collate latin1_german2_ci default NULL,
  `event_day1` int(2) default NULL,
  `event_day2` int(2) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `article` (`article`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  ;

Anyone have any idea why it wouldn't like the second column to look in?

Answer (score 5):

Well define fulltext index on both fields:

```
FULLTEXT KEY title_article_fx (title, article)
```